# How can I changing or replace user's avatar without plugins?

Tags: gravatar

I want to change Gravatar from my [website](http://www.answersmode.com). But I don't know how to change it? 
Please some one help me.
I do not want to use plugins.
I need step by step instructions because I'm not expert.

Comment: Have you actually researched anything. There are questions on this site that handled this before. Where exactly are you stuck and where is your effort. Please file an [edit] with all of this info

Answer (score -2):

1 Visit [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/site/signup/) website

2 Sign in to Gravatar with your WordPress.com account. If you don’t have a WordPress.com   account then you need to create one.

3 Upload your avatar ( profile picture ).

and you are done with it.

Comment: I think he wants to do this to users as well as himself.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Now I have created my Gravatar but you did not say how can I use it. I want to use my avator in this website's profile. [Answers Mode](http://www.answersmode.com/member/agendadirectory/)  
 Please help me.

Comment: Yes, I wants to do this to users as well as myself.